# How do I replicate PHP's hash_hmac function in C++?

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography, hmac, hmacsha1

I'm trying to replicate PHP's hash_hmac function in C++ using wincrypt. Someone sent me [this MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program--creating-an-hmac)
titled "Example C Program: Creating an HMAC". I copy all of the code and the result prints out

> The hash is:  48 f2 57 38 29 29 43 16 fd f4 db 58 31 e1 0c 74 48 8e d4 e2

The sample data in this case uses "password" and "message". So now I switch over to the PHP function and I call it two ways to make sure the order is right:

```
echo(hash_hmac('sha1', "password", "message", false));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo(hash_hmac('sha1', "message", "password", false));
```

And this prints out

```
f5959d1d5c133fd9368218e1ffde3075382d7fd7
4c2de361ba8958558de3d049ed1fb5c115656e65
```

So none of the hashes are matching. What is the difference here? How do I get the C++ one to match the PHP?

I'm being forced to edit this question to explain why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113805/hmac-with-cryptography-api-c-c) doesn't help me. The two answers are "use openssl" and "it's impossible". Firstly, openssl isn't an option. Second, it IS possible. It has to be, because PHP is written in C++ as are other third party libraries that do it...

Full code below in case the MS page dies someday.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

int main()
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Declare variables.
//
// hProv:           Handle to a cryptographic service provider (CSP). 
//                  This example retrieves the default provider for  
//                  the PROV_RSA_FULL provider type.  
// hHash:           Handle to the hash object needed to create a hash.
// hKey:            Handle to a symmetric key. This example creates a 
//                  key for the RC4 algorithm.
// hHmacHash:       Handle to an HMAC hash.
// pbHash:          Pointer to the hash.
// dwDataLen:       Length, in bytes, of the hash.
// Data1:           Password string used to create a symmetric key.
// Data2:           Message string to be hashed.
// HmacInfo:        Instance of an HMAC_INFO structure that contains 
//                  information about the HMAC hash.
// 
HCRYPTPROV  hProv       = NULL;
HCRYPTHASH  hHash       = NULL;
HCRYPTKEY   hKey        = NULL;
HCRYPTHASH  hHmacHash   = NULL;
PBYTE       pbHash      = NULL;
DWORD       dwDataLen   = 0;
BYTE        Data1[]     = {0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64};
BYTE        Data2[]     = {0x6D,0x65,0x73,0x73,0x61,0x67,0x65};
HMAC_INFO   HmacInfo;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Zero the HMAC_INFO structure and use the SHA1 algorithm for
// hashing.

ZeroMemory(&HmacInfo, sizeof(HmacInfo));
HmacInfo.HashAlgid = CALG_SHA1;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Acquire a handle to the default RSA cryptographic service provider.

if (!CryptAcquireContext(
    &hProv,                   // handle of the CSP
    NULL,                     // key container name
    NULL,                     // CSP name
    PROV_RSA_FULL,            // provider type
    CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))     // no key access is requested
{
   printf(" Error in AcquireContext 0x%08x \n",
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Derive a symmetric key from a hash object by performing the
// following steps:
//    1. Call CryptCreateHash to retrieve a handle to a hash object.
//    2. Call CryptHashData to add a text string (password) to the 
//       hash object.
//    3. Call CryptDeriveKey to create the symmetric key from the
//       hashed password derived in step 2.
// You will use the key later to create an HMAC hash object. 

if (!CryptCreateHash(
    hProv,                    // handle of the CSP
    CALG_SHA1,                // hash algorithm to use
    0,                        // hash key
    0,                        // reserved
    &hHash))                  // address of hash object handle
{
   printf("Error in CryptCreateHash 0x%08x \n",
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

if (!CryptHashData(
    hHash,                    // handle of the hash object
    Data1,                    // password to hash
    sizeof(Data1),            // number of bytes of data to add
    0))                       // flags
{
   printf("Error in CryptHashData 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

if (!CryptDeriveKey(
    hProv,                    // handle of the CSP
    CALG_RC4,                 // algorithm ID
    hHash,                    // handle to the hash object
    0,                        // flags
    &hKey))                   // address of the key handle
{
   printf("Error in CryptDeriveKey 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create an HMAC by performing the following steps:
//    1. Call CryptCreateHash to create a hash object and retrieve 
//       a handle to it.
//    2. Call CryptSetHashParam to set the instance of the HMAC_INFO 
//       structure into the hash object.
//    3. Call CryptHashData to compute a hash of the message.
//    4. Call CryptGetHashParam to retrieve the size, in bytes, of
//       the hash.
//    5. Call malloc to allocate memory for the hash.
//    6. Call CryptGetHashParam again to retrieve the HMAC hash.

if (!CryptCreateHash(
    hProv,                    // handle of the CSP.
    CALG_HMAC,                // HMAC hash algorithm ID
    hKey,                     // key for the hash (see above)
    0,                        // reserved
    &hHmacHash))              // address of the hash handle
{
   printf("Error in CryptCreateHash 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

if (!CryptSetHashParam(
    hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
    HP_HMAC_INFO,             // setting an HMAC_INFO object
    (BYTE*)&HmacInfo,         // the HMAC_INFO object
    0))                       // reserved
{
   printf("Error in CryptSetHashParam 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

if (!CryptHashData(
    hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
    Data2,                    // message to hash
    sizeof(Data2),            // number of bytes of data to add
    0))                       // flags
{
   printf("Error in CryptHashData 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Call CryptGetHashParam twice. Call it the first time to retrieve
// the size, in bytes, of the hash. Allocate memory. Then call 
// CryptGetHashParam again to retrieve the hash value.

if (!CryptGetHashParam(
    hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
    HP_HASHVAL,               // query on the hash value
    NULL,                     // filled on second call
    &dwDataLen,               // length, in bytes, of the hash
    0))
{
   printf("Error in CryptGetHashParam 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

pbHash = (BYTE*)malloc(dwDataLen);
if(NULL == pbHash) 
{
   printf("unable to allocate memory\n");
   goto ErrorExit;
}
    
if (!CryptGetHashParam(
    hHmacHash,                 // handle of the HMAC hash object
    HP_HASHVAL,                // query on the hash value
    pbHash,                    // pointer to the HMAC hash value
    &dwDataLen,                // length, in bytes, of the hash
    0))
{
   printf("Error in CryptGetHashParam 0x%08x \n", GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

// Print the hash to the console.

printf("The hash is:  ");
for(DWORD i = 0 ; i < dwDataLen ; i++) 
{
   printf("%2.2x ",pbHash[i]);
}
printf("\n");

// Free resources.
ErrorExit:
    if(hHmacHash)
        CryptDestroyHash(hHmacHash);
    if(hKey)
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    if(hHash)
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);    
    if(hProv)
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    if(pbHash)
        free(pbHash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: CryptDeriveKey is a mystery, I suggest using openssl.

Comment: [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) is not specific to PHP. And it has no RC4-based key derivation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HMAC with Cryptography API C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113805/hmac-with-cryptography-api-c-c)

Comment: @Olivier Weirdly that is the same question, but the answers are "it's impossible" and "use a different library" while the answer by Kazz seems to be possible and not use openssl...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plaintext key, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

int main()
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Declare variables.
    //
    // hProv:           Handle to a cryptographic service provider (CSP). 
    //                  This example retrieves the default provider for  
    //                  the PROV_RSA_FULL provider type.  
    // hHash:           Handle to the hash object needed to create a hash.
    // hKey:            Handle to a symmetric key. This example creates a 
    //                  key for the RC4 algorithm.
    // hHmacHash:       Handle to an HMAC hash.
    // pbHash:          Pointer to the hash.
    // dwDataLen:       Length, in bytes, of the hash.
    // Data1:           Password string used to create a symmetric key.
    // Data2:           Message string to be hashed.
    // HmacInfo:        Instance of an HMAC_INFO structure that contains 
    //                  information about the HMAC hash.
    // 
    HCRYPTPROV  hProv = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY   hKey = NULL;
    HCRYPTHASH  hHmacHash = NULL;
    PBYTE       pbHash = NULL;
    DWORD       dwDataLen = 0;
    BYTE        Data1[] = { 0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64 };
    BYTE        Data2[] = { 0x6D,0x65,0x73,0x73,0x61,0x67,0x65 };
    HMAC_INFO   HmacInfo;

    struct KEYBLOB
    {
        BLOBHEADER header;
        DWORD size;
    };

    struct KEYBLOB* keyblob = NULL;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Zero the HMAC_INFO structure and use the SHA1 algorithm for
    // hashing.

    ZeroMemory(&HmacInfo, sizeof(HmacInfo));
    HmacInfo.HashAlgid = CALG_SHA1;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Acquire a handle to the default RSA cryptographic service provider.

    if (!CryptAcquireContext(
        &hProv,                   // handle of the CSP
        NULL,                     // key container name
        NULL,                     // CSP name
        PROV_RSA_FULL,            // provider type
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))     // no key access is requested
    {
        printf(" Error in AcquireContext 0x%08x \n",
            GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    keyblob = (KEYBLOB*)malloc(sizeof(KEYBLOB) + sizeof(Data1));
    if (keyblob == NULL) {
        printf("Error malloc failed to allocate memory of %zu bytes\n",
            sizeof(KEYBLOB) + sizeof(Data1));
        goto ErrorExit;
    }
    keyblob->header.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
    keyblob->header.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
    keyblob->header.reserved = 0;
    keyblob->header.aiKeyAlg = CALG_RC2;

    keyblob->size = sizeof(Data1);

    memcpy((PBYTE)keyblob + sizeof(KEYBLOB), Data1, sizeof(Data1));

    if (!CryptImportKey(
        hProv,
        (PBYTE)keyblob,
        sizeof(KEYBLOB) + sizeof(Data1),
        0,
        CRYPT_IPSEC_HMAC_KEY,
        &hKey))
    {
        printf("Error in CryptImportKey 0x%08x \n",
            GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create an HMAC by performing the following steps:
    //    1. Call CryptCreateHash to create a hash object and retrieve 
    //       a handle to it.
    //    2. Call CryptSetHashParam to set the instance of the HMAC_INFO 
    //       structure into the hash object.
    //    3. Call CryptHashData to compute a hash of the message.
    //    4. Call CryptGetHashParam to retrieve the size, in bytes, of
    //       the hash.
    //    5. Call malloc to allocate memory for the hash.
    //    6. Call CryptGetHashParam again to retrieve the HMAC hash.

    if (!CryptCreateHash(
        hProv,                    // handle of the CSP.
        CALG_HMAC,                // HMAC hash algorithm ID
        hKey,                     // key for the hash (see above)
        0,                        // reserved
        &hHmacHash))              // address of the hash handle
    {
        printf("Error in CryptCreateHash 0x%08x \n",
            GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    if (!CryptSetHashParam(
        hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
        HP_HMAC_INFO,             // setting an HMAC_INFO object
        (BYTE*)&HmacInfo,         // the HMAC_INFO object
        0))                       // reserved
    {
        printf("Error in CryptSetHashParam 0x%08x \n",
            GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(
        hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
        Data2,                    // message to hash
        sizeof(Data2),            // number of bytes of data to add
        0))                       // flags
    {
        printf("Error in CryptHashData 0x%08x \n",
            GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Call CryptGetHashParam twice. Call it the first time to retrieve
    // the size, in bytes, of the hash. Allocate memory. Then call 
    // CryptGetHashParam again to retrieve the hash value.

    if (!CryptGetHashParam(
        hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
        HP_HASHVAL,               // query on the hash value
        NULL,                     // filled on second call
        &dwDataLen,               // length, in bytes, of the hash
        0))
    {
        printf("Error in CryptGetHashParam 0x%08x \n",
            GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    pbHash = (BYTE*)malloc(dwDataLen);
    if (NULL == pbHash)
    {
        printf("unable to allocate memory\n");
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    if (!CryptGetHashParam(
        hHmacHash,                 // handle of the HMAC hash object
        HP_HASHVAL,                // query on the hash value
        pbHash,                    // pointer to the HMAC hash value
        &dwDataLen,                // length, in bytes, of the hash
        0))
    {
        printf("Error in CryptGetHashParam 0x%08x \n", GetLastError());
        goto ErrorExit;
    }

    // Print the hash to the console.

    printf("The hash is:  ");
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwDataLen; i++)
    {
        printf("%2.2x ", pbHash[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Free resources.
ErrorExit:
    if (hHmacHash)
        CryptDestroyHash(hHmacHash);
    if (hKey)
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    if (keyblob)
        free(keyblob);
    if (hProv)
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    if (pbHash)
        free(pbHash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kazz. The related question linked in the comments above (and in my edit) say this is impossible. I guess that makes you some kind of wizard.